# C#: Как поменять тип переменной? Или удалить ее, а затем создать заново

Tags: c#

Имеется объект `data`:

```cs
Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Я поработал с этим словарем, после чего мне нужно создать новый словарь **с таким же именем** (для удобства работы), но другими параметрами значения и ключа:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Разумеется, я не смогу это скомпилировать, потому что у меня уже есть объект `data`. Как я могу перезаписать **тип** объекта? Может можно как-то удалить `data`, чтобы затем создать заново?

---

Нужно чтобы как в языках с динамической типизацией:

```py
data = [1, 2, 3]
data = 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: По идее, вы не должны попадать в такую ситуацию, где нужна коллекция из разных типов. Если вы столкнулись с подобной ситуацией, значит что-то пошло не так до того как вы с ней столкнулись. Какую именно задачу вы решаете? [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567)

Comment: @aepot я работаю с json-объектами и мне постоянно нужно перезаписывать объект `data`, потому что в значениях ключей всегда разные типы данных. А постоянно придумывать новое название переменной не хочется

Comment: Приведите пример. Несмотря на то что ответ ниже работает, он является небезопасным и неэффективным. `dynamic` работает медленнее обычных типов и ест больше памяти. Конечно если вам это безразлично, то и это сойдет. Если же хотите разобраться, покажите ситуацию целиком с данными и кодом, с ними работающим.

Comment: Кстати, чем вам `Dictionary<string, object>` не угодил? В качестве значения у него может же быть любой тип. Проблемы с десереализацией? Какие именно?

Comment: В принципе, да, `Dictionary<string, object>` подойдет в любом случае. Просто приводить к нужному типу постоянно не хочется. Хочется сразу же указать его

Comment: Но что именно приводить и зачем приводить, вы конечно же не покажете? Я уже решал схожую проблему, но без понятия, подойдет ли вам решение. И так же не в курсе, что же это за проблема.

Comment: В принципе, уже все ок. Мне просто было крайне непривычно после Python, где json-объект с любыми типами значений можно было считать в один словарь и все. А здесь нужно указывать тип значений ключей, либо приводить `object` к нужному типу. Так или иначе я уже разобрался и готов удалить вопрос, чтобы не сбивать с толку

Comment: Сдается мне, вам вообще не нужен словарь. Но как знаете. Можете отдельный вопрос задать, где выложить данные и структуры, куда вы их читаете. И сам код, само собой. А мы подскажем, все ли с этим хорошо, и можно ли улучшить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать тип [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic):

```
dynamic data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
data["key"] = 3;
Console.WriteLine(data["key"]);
data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
data["key"] = "value";
Console.WriteLine(data["key"]);
```

**Warning:** при программирование на C# не принято использовать такие конструкции, т.к. их применение делает код менее читаемым

Comment: .. а еще медленным и кушающим много памяти.

Comment: почему бы просто не использовать блоки кода, раз уж на то пошло `{ ... } { ... }`? `dynamic` может пригодиться там, где типы неизвесны на этапе компиляции, хотя и там оно - сомнительное удовольствие. А у вас вполне себе всё известно.